# WCF service in Windows service on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, wcf, amazon-ec2, windows-services

I'm fairly new to EC2, hopefully someone can point me into the correct direction.  I have a WCF Service hosted in Windows Service and would like to run this on EC2. I set up an EC2 account with Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server Express.  I put my service out there and ran it, I'm able to test and connect to it from the browser with the private IP on the VM, but when I try to connect to the service from my computer with the Public IP, I'm not able to do so.

Am I missing some important configuration or am I totally off?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm testing this with port 8080 and added that to the Permission Groups. I also tried to assigned an elastic IP to the instance.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

EC2 provides security groups, which are essentially a firewall external to the machine.  The default security group will allow SSH and RDP connections.  If you want requests for port 8080 to be received by the VM, update the security group settings for the VM.  You can do this interactively from the Amazon Management Console.

You also need to configure the firewall running in the windows VM, but it appears you did this when you added the service to the 'Permission Groups'.